# Repair of antique standing lamp light fitting (UK)

Tags: lamp

I have broken this light fitting off an antique wooden lamp stand. It's a bayonet fitting, which screws onto a brass screw thread. Is this a standard fitting? Does anyone know where I could get one in the UK? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The last time I was in Broken & Quick they still had those light fittings - as I nearly got two to make a couple of desklamps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a standard engineering fitting, but they are readily available.

The older ones are usually 1/2" BSB (not BSP British Standard Pipe, but **BSB British Standard Brass**. This is 26tpi, same as cycle thread, but a different thread form: 55 degree instead of 60.

https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Products/BG252.html

Newer studded threads are M10 and M13 metric threads.

You can get adapters to fit a 1/2" on a 3/8" or a 10mm threaded stud

https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Products/LY1110.html

This site has lots of bits for more unusual applications.

https://www.lampsandlights.co.uk/lighting-components.php

Answer (score 0):

The brass screw threads are standard but the rest of the fixture looks unique. You have a few of options: Take the fixture to a lighting store and try to get an exact duplicate or go to a home store and look for something close. Do you want to have the same type/size of bulb? If not, there are quite a few choices. Good luck from the USA.

Comment: If the lamp really is antique, I don't think that fitting is original.  I think it would originally have been Bakelite - which means the OP probably doesn't care about an exact replacement.

Answer (score 0):

That brass thing looks like a pretty standard hickey. The entire white plastic  assembly above it gets replaced as a unit, that is the lamp socket, and it may have an internal switch as well.

Expect to find a huge variety of replacement sockets, and if the socket type has been annoying you, this is your opportunity to change it.

Don't be surprised if the replacement looks quite different from this unit.  I generally expect to find steel ones that are plated to look brass.